# How would get two div tags to align horizontally

Tags: html, css

Okay so I have two div elements that I want to align vertically, the elements are identified as "NavBar" and "title" I have tried multiple times to align them but nothing seems to work... Any help would be great and the code is below.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
div.NavBar {
 color: blue;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 25%;
 min-width: 140px;
 flex: 1;
}
div.title {
 color: purple;
 text-align: center;
 
}
div.container {
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.png' type='image/png'/ >
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Bobby The Death Mage</title>
        <script src="code.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>        
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="NavBar">
    <h1>Nav Bar<BR>---------------</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Site Title<BR>--------------------------------------------</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you want to do?

Comment: div class="Nav Bar"> means you have 2 class 1 is "Nav" and secend is "Bar"
where is your .help div ?? <BR> means break the line

Comment: Add ```float: left``` to the first div which is having container class.

Comment: I would recommend you to use bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to align the 2 divs horizontally, you're closing the `</div>` of "container" before "title", close it after the "title" div block https://jsfiddle.net/L9n8jf2y/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="help">
    <h1>Nav Bar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Site Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this one worked thanks for the help, now how would I set a 10px space between them? would i simply use margin-left: 10px; ?

Comment: @lecidious technically, yes, but I have updated the fiddle, take a look. That is the proper way to do it, I believe. Easy to change colors, etc. If there is any line in the code that you dont understand, let me know

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.png' type='image/png'/ >
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Bobby The Death Mage</title>
            <script src="code.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>        
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class="container">
       <div class="Nav Bar">
        <h1>Nav Bar<BR>---------------</h1>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Site Title<BR>--------------------------------------------</h1>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you close the container div after NavBar.. so according to your code here is the answer just place the container div end after class title /div> close and add a extra class into container class div- [https://jsfiddle.net/exwbfxa8/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/exwbfxa8/1/)

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
div.v_align {
  display: inline-flex;
}
div.NavBar {
  color: blue;
  background-color: white;
}
div.title {
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container v_align">
  <div class="NavBar">
    <h1>Nav Bar--------------</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="title">
    <h1>Site Title----------------------</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```